# SQL Get difference between two fields in a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a view which shows:

```
d_date      d_shop  d_qty  r_date     r_shop  r_qty
12-oct-12   ABC     20     12-oct-12  XYZ     20
12-oct-12   ABC     15     12-oct-12  XYZ     0
12-oct-12   XYZ     10     12-oct-12  ABC     10
12-oct-12   ABC     25     12-oct-12  XYZ     10
12-oct-12   XYZ     10     12-oct-12  ABC     0
```

I want to check the difference between receive_qty and dispatch_qty of the `receive_shop`

i.e. the correct answer will be:

```
r_date     r_shop  r_qty
12-oct-12  XYZ     10
```

I am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: It is super unclear how to get the results you want. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear on the question, but maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
select r_date, d_shop, sum(d_qty)-sum(r_qty)
from asdf
group by r_date, d_shop
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22d55/10/0)

Comment: tried but it didn't worked out..